# Problems with Source.fromURL when trying to close it in finally block

Tags: scala

Following code snippet works fine:

```
def using[A, B <: {def close(): Unit}] (closeable: B) (f: B => A): A =
  try { f(closeable) } finally { closeable.close() }

def loadDictionaryFromNet():List[String] =
  using(Source.fromURL("http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_caps.txt", "UTF-8"))(_.getLines().toList)

  val dictionary = loadDictionaryFromNet() filter(_.forall(_.isLetter))
```

But when I try to change the type to `Seq[String]` like below:

```
def using[A, B <: {def close(): Unit}] (closeable: B) (f: B => A): A =
  try { f(closeable) } finally { closeable.close() }

def loadDictionaryFromNet():Seq[String] =
  using(Source.fromURL("http://www.mieliestronk.com/corncob_caps.txt", "UTF-8"))(_.getLines().toSeq)

  val dictionary = loadDictionaryFromNet() filter(_.forall(_.isLetter))
```

Then it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: stream is closed
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(HttpURLConnection.java:3348)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3373)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    ...
```

Also when I change type to `IndexedSeq` it works again.

It "feels" like `toSeq` produces in fact some partially-lazy stream which is not consumed fully immediately but has some delay.

Could you explain what happens under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you are right. Let's track it down starting from `Source.fromURL`:

1. `Source.fromURL` => `scala.io.BufferedSource`
2. `BufferedSource.getLines` => `BufferedLineIterator`
3. `BufferedLineIterator.toSeq` is called from `scala.collection.TraversableOnce`
4. `TraversableOnce` implements method `toSeq` as: `def toSeq: Seq[A] = toStream`
5. Implementation of `toStream` is taken from class `Iterator`.

Implementation is the following:

```
def toStream: Stream[A] =
  if (self.hasNext) Stream.cons(self.next(), self.toStream)
  else Stream.empty[A]
```

Phew, quite a journey. Yes, you end up constructing a stream which is lazy and therefore you get exception you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas why `TraversableOnce`  uses the `Stream` in this case? I first thought that probably it has something to do with the fact that we deal with `BufferedSource` which has part of lazyness baked in it by principle. But cannot say for sure.